# How to Set required attributes in aws cognito user pool using aws cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

[Aws cognito console screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63Ru2.png)

While creating user-pool using cloudformation template i wanted to add the following attributes(marked in the attached image link). I didn't find anything helpful in the AWS documentation.

It allows setting up Alias attributes as said in the aws cloudformation cognito [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpool.html#cfn-cognito-userpool-aliasattributes).

Has anybody tried this or has any idea regarding this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I managed to get it done using the schema attribute of the AWS::cognito::UserPool:

```
"myApiUserPool": {
  "Type": "AWS::Cognito::UserPool",
  "Properties": {
    "AdminCreateUserConfig": {
      "AllowAdminCreateUserOnly": true
    },
    "Schema": [
      {
        "Mutable": false,
        "Name": "email",
        "Required": true
      },
      {
        "Mutable": false,
        "Name": "family_name",
        "Required": true
      },
      {
        "Mutable": false,
        "Name": "name",
        "Required": true
      }
    ],
    "AutoVerifiedAttributes": [
      "email"
    ],
    "UserPoolName": {
      "Fn::Sub": "myApiUserPool${envParameter}"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Amazon needs to shame that they not specified that required attributes should have a different structure. I spent a lot of time until I found your example.

Answer (score 16):

Here is the example with YAML.

Note: you cannot just update a attribute you need to delete the userpool and create it again with the new attributes (just comment out your pool section and redeploy it). Otherwise it will ask for a `AttributeDataType`, and if you include it, it will create a custom attribute instead of standard one.

```
CognitoUserPool:
  Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
  Properties:
    # Generate a name based on the stage
    UserPoolName: ${self:custom.stage}-cfp-user-pool
    AliasAttributes:
      - phone_number
      - email
      - preferred_username
    Policies:
      PasswordPolicy:
        MinimumLength: 8
    Schema:
      - Name: email
        Required: true
        Mutable: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on @jWang1 and considering **you don't want to delete a user pool** with lots of active users but you really need to add a parameter during for sign up process, then you can just add a [custom attribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html) to the template and enforce it as **required** through your authentication library or custom implementation

The minimum parameters to achieve this are:

```
UserPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    Properties:
        Schema:
        -
          Name: <attr name>
          AttributeDataType: Boolean | DateTime | Number | String
```

Comment: During validation the key is expected as "custom:<attr name>"